# Content Porter 2009 SP2 - Unable to map all paths to URIs

Tags: 2011, content-porter-2009, webdav

Running a Content Porter import for a single component and its failing with the following error:

> Error details: (TCMDAL::ExecuteRequest:Content Manager returned an
>   error)   (Cause=true)  Unable to map all paths to URIs. (Cause=false) 
>   Unable to save Component (tcm:0-0-0). (Callstack)  Request.SaveItem -
>   Component.Save - XMLState.Save -
>   Tridion.ContentManager.BLFacade.ContentManagement.VersionedItemFacade.CreateAndCheckIn(UserContext,String,Boolean)
>   - Tridion.ContentManager.ContentManagement.VersionedItem.Save() - Tridion.ContentManager.ContentManagement.VersionedItem.Save(Boolean) -
>   Tridion.ContentManager.IdentifiableObject.Save(SaveEventArgs) -
>   Tridion.ContentManager.UrlConversion.Convert()
>   (TCMDAL::Communications::CheckResponseForErrors)  Errors encountered
>   during check of response (TCMDAL::Communications::ExecuteRequest) 
>   Error while executing request (TCMDAL::TCMItem:Create)  Error while
>   creating item based on given XML

I think the unable to map error is due to a problem with a WebDAV path (?) - for some reason a path cant be converted to a Tcm - usually because a dependency is missing.

But I've checked all the component links, multimedia, schema, folder etc and all exist on the target.

The [log is here](https://gist.github.com/neilgibbons/7580850) - but it doesn't seem to show *which* path caused the problem(unless I'm mis-reading).
Is there anyway to find out - or any other advice on tackling this issue (short of just recreating the component by hand!)?

NB - this was initially part of a wider import where all other components where successfully imported, even ones based on the same schema as this component!

**UPDATE**

[Component Xml can be seen here.](https://gist.github.com/neilgibbons/7582185)

[Content Porter Xml can be seen here](https://gist.github.com/neilgibbons/7582281)

Comment: Could you please post component XML?

Comment: +1 we can't answer without component xml.
Also - my suggestion find this component in package - there you'll see all dependencies and will be able to analyze, which of them is missed.

Comment: Updated with links to component and content porter Xml. Like I said though, I've checked all the dependencies and they are all on the target system. I dont understand why the Content Porter log cant just identify *which* dependency its failed on!

Comment: Found it - god damn! It appears my component has been through a schema change so the component Xml has a field value that isn't supported in my schema. Sya4eg, your comment led me to this so feel free to post as an answer and I'll accept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My suggestion is to find this Component XML in the Content Porter package - there you'll see all dependencies and will be able to analyze which of them are missing.

Answer (score 2):

Normally it will be a Dependency issue, I think you might have missed a category and/or keyword, kindly check if you have imported those as well.